# Get function object of caller in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, callstack

In playing with `inspect` and reading the other questions here, I still cannot figure out how to get the function *object* of the caller more cleanly than to load the module by its path and then find the function within that.

In other words, how would you complete the following so that `caller()` returns a method object?

```
import inspect

def caller():
    frame = inspect.stack()[2]
    code = frame[0]
    path = frame[1]
    line = frame[2] 
    name = frame[3] # function NAME string
    # TODO: now what?
    return func

def cry_wolf():
    func = caller()
    print "%s cried 'WOLF!'" % (func.__name__,)

def peter():
    cry_wolf()
```

Remember, I already know the function name but what I'm trying to access is the function object that the calling code is running in. The result desired is:

```
peter cried 'WOLF!'
```

DONE! Thanks to user 61612, I have completed this code:

```
import imp, inspect, sys

def caller():
    frame = inspect.stack()[2]
    code = frame[0]
    path = frame[1]
    line = frame[2] 
    name = frame[3]
    return code.f_globals[name]

def cry_wolf():
    func = caller()
    print "%s cried 'WOLF!'" % (func.__name__,)

def peter():
    cry_wolf()
```

Awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frame objects have the [`f_globals` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html?highlight=f_globals#types-and-members):

```
import inspect

def caller():
    tup = inspect.stack()[2]
    return tup[0].f_globals[tup[3]] # <function peter at address>

def cry_wolf():
    func = caller()
    print("%s cried 'WOLF!'" % (func.__name__,)) # peter cried 'WOLF!'

def peter():
    cry_wolf()
```

Comment: This is great, only because of my typo of stack frame `[1]` instead of `[2]`, you ended up with the wrong frame. I adapted your code into my solution which I put in the question. Thank you!

Comment: @NeilC.Obremski yeah, I wasn't sure if this was the right frame :)

Comment: @NeilC.Obremski anyway, I updated the answer to make it clear